# Spanned archives with more than 65534 segments are not supported at this time

Tags: asp.net, zip, dotnetzip

Our current implementation on our ASP.net website doesn't support Zip64 which it needs to, so we're moving from `System.IO.Compression` over to `DotNetZip`:
https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip

This small archive:
https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip/files/10184907/Zip.zip

Throws the error:

> Spanned archives with more than 65534 segments are not supported at this time.

The code sample simply attempts to open the Zip file:

```
using (var data = new MemoryStream(fileBytes.ToArray()))
{
    using (var archive = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(data))
    {
        ....
    }
```

I'm a little unsure what the issue is here, is there an easy workaround or is there a better altnerative library?

Comment: The [nuget package page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) links to this GitHub repo https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd and not the one you mention on your question (which seems to be inactive). Perhaps you can open an issue there instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand what does mean to have *spanned* zip file.  That means that a zip is split into more files.

The file you have linked appears not to be such file:

```
Archive:  Zip.zip
There is no zipfile comment.

End-of-central-directory record:
-------------------------------

  Zip archive file size:                    646370 (000000000009DCE2h)
  Actual end-cent-dir record offset:        646272 (000000000009DC80h)
  Expected end-cent-dir record offset:      646272 (000000000009DC80h)
  (based on the length of the central directory and its expected offset)

  This zipfile constitutes the sole disk of a single-part archive; its
  central directory contains 25 entries.
  The central directory is 3521 (0000000000000DC1h) bytes long,
  and its (expected) offset in bytes from the beginning of the zipfile
  is 642751 (000000000009CEBFh).
...
```

I think the problem is how you try to read the file with `fileBytes.ToArray()`.  The `data` variable should be a *filename* and not `fileBytes.ToArray()`.

If you look at the provided example, on how to read zip file, from the git you can see that on [line 53](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip/blob/master/Examples/c%23/ReadZip/ReadZip.cs#L53) you get `ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(args[0], options)`, where args[0] is a zip filename.

Here is the complete example form the git:

```cs
/ ReadZip.cs
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (c) 2006-2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
//
// This example is released under the Microsoft Public License .
// See the license.txt file accompanying this release for
// full details.
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// This simple example utility simply reads a zip archive and extracts
// all elements in it, to the specified target directory.
//
// compile with:
//     csc /target:exe /r:Ionic.Zip.dll /out:ReadZip.exe ReadZip.cs
//
// Wed, 29 Mar 2006  14:36
//


using System;
using Ionic.Zip;

namespace Ionic.Zip.Examples
{
    public class ReadZip
    {
        private static void Usage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("usage:\n  ReadZip2 <zipfile> <unpackdirectory>");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }


        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {

            if (args.Length != 2) Usage();
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(args[0]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That zip file does not exist!\n");
                Usage();
            }

            try
            {
                // Specifying Console.Out here causes diagnostic msgs to be sent to the Console
                // In a WinForms or WPF or Web app, you could specify nothing, or an alternate
                // TextWriter to capture diagnostic messages.

                var options = new ReadOptions { StatusMessageWriter = System.Console.Out };
                using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(args[0], options))
                {
                    // This call to ExtractAll() assumes:
                    //   - none of the entries are password-protected.
                    //   - want to extract all entries to current working directory
                    //   - none of the files in the zip already exist in the directory;
                    //     if they do, the method will throw.
                    zip.ExtractAll(args[1]);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex1)
            {
                System.Console.Error.WriteLine("exception: " + ex1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** - the above posted zip file still generates the above error.  I have checked the source to find out where is the culprit:

It thinks it is a spanned archive based on [this read](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip/blob/7ac10dc7793cbf21212848e9814334ee946f26d3/Zip/ZipFile.Read.cs#L610).  [It tries to read](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip/blob/7ac10dc7793cbf21212848e9814334ee946f26d3/Zip/ZipFile.Read.cs#L612) a 2 bytes (that are converted to  16-bit unsigned integer ) from the `block` starting at 2nd position.  If the converted value is `==0xFFFF` then it considers the file as spanning file with more than 65534 segments.  Probably there is some bug in the packing of the zip file which makes the *DotNetZip* fail.

Comment: I tried `ZipFile.Read(pathToZipFile)` as well as `ZipFile.Read(pathToZipFile, options)` but I get the same error. Were you able to run it successfully?

Comment: @TasosK. Nope, the issue is probably the zip file itself.  I will edit the answer with the code I think is responsible for the behaviour.

Comment: @Tukan thanks for this, archive is generated using ZiPJS:  
https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/

We'll post a link to this answer as an issue for that library

Comment: Interesting point, if I upload the zip it fails with the error in the OP.  If I open the zip in Winrar on Windows, and add another file to it, then upload it it now works.  To me this does support the fact that the zip generation is buggy, and Winrar fixes the issue when it recreates the archive.

Comment: @TomGullen you are welcome.  It is always tricky to find where the issue lies.  In this case the generator appears to be incorrect.  It was reading the *DotNetZip* source that gave it away.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [SharpZipLib nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib) you can use as an alternative.

The code below runs successfully with input the file you posted

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    string filename = "../../../Zip.zip";

    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
    ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile zf = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile(fs);
    foreach (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry zipEntry in zf)
    {
        string entryFileName = zipEntry.Name;
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + entryFileName);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Hello, World!
File: scripts/c3runtime.js
File: data.json
File: style.css
File: scripts/offlineclient.js
File: images/shared-0-sheet1.png
File: images/tiledbackground-sheet0.png
File: images/shared-0-sheet0.png
File: appmanifest.json
File: scripts/main.js
File: workermain.js
File: scripts/dispatchworker.js
File: scripts/jobworker.js
File: scripts/supportcheck.js
File: icons/icon-16.png
File: icons/icon-32.png
File: icons/icon-128.png
File: icons/icon-256.png
File: icons/icon-64.png
File: icons/icon-512.png
File: icons/loading-logo.png
File: index.html
File: arcade.json
File: scripts/register-sw.js
File: sw.js
File: offline.json
```

P.S. I have worked with both libraries in the past and I have found that DotNetZip is easier to work with, but for this case only SharpZipLib works :).

Comment: Much appreciated, this library does indeed work.  Both these answers are useful in different ways and I'm sorry but I have to give the bounty to the other question as I believe they've correctly identified a bug in the zip creation which is the underlying cause.  Appreciate your help though!